# Using RxJS in Angular with conditional / combined subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

in my Angular App I have an API service like so that contains two methods:

```
addComment(id: string, comment: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`api/${encodeURIComponent(id)}/comment`, { comment }).pipe(
      map(this.apiUtils.extractData)
    );
  }


closeAccount(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`api/${encodeURIComponent(id)}/closeaccount`, {}).pipe(
      map(this.apiUtils.extractData)
    );
}
```

Now in my app I have a component where I can close a user account and if a comment is added I wish to add a comment before closing the account, but this is conditional, sometimes a user doesn't need to add a comment before closing an account. In my component file I have created a method for this but I am  a bit stuck with something... here is my component code where I collect my user data and comment from a form. If we have a comment we call the api to add the comment and when that resolves I call the API to close the account. If no comment has been submitted I just call the api to close the account. This is okay, but hardly eloquent! Please note I have reduced the code to improve readability.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            public apiService: ApiService) {}

// i have omitted the code where I create my form and validation

closeAccount(): void {
    // get values from my form
    const id = this.closeAccountForm.controls.id.value;
    const comment = this.closeAccountForm.controls.closeAccountComment.value; 

    if (comment) {
        this.apiService.addComment(id, comment).subscribe(() => {
            this.apiService.closeAccount(id).subscribe(() => {
                // now do something
            });
        })
    } else {  
        this.apiService.closeAccount(id).subscribe(() => {
            // now do something
        });
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I can reduce the code and prevent the duplication of calling the closeAccount method. Does RxJS provide a way for me to apply the conditional logic in a method? What I have above works but is pretty ugly!

I'm currently reading the docs but sometimes people can provide an answer quicker. If I find an answer/solution I shall provide it here. Many thanks in advance. If my wording is bad please say so and I shall rework my question.

Comment: To prevent code duplication, just extract the closeAccount calls to another function. From what you're showing, I think it does make sense an if-else. You're doing different actions based on user input, so nothing wrong here. One thing you could do, if you don't need the comment value inside the add comment subscribe, is using the switchMap pipe in the addComment to switch to the closeAccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const preCloseAction = comment ? this.apiService.addComment(...) : of(null);

preCloseAction.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.apiService.closeAccount(id))
).subscribe(() => {
  // now do something
})
```

or, if the result of comment doesnt matter during closeAccount call

```
concat(
  !comment ? EMPTY : this.apiService.addComment(...),
  this.apiService.closeAccount(id)
).pipe(last()).subscribe(() => {
  // now do something
})
```

Comment: The `concat()` option will trigger 2 next notifications if there's a comment (one for each observable). So if you only want to trigger the `do something` once, you'll have to either add `.pipe(last())` before subscribe if you're interested in the `closeAccount` response, or provide an observer for the `complete` notification instead if not interested.

Comment: ty, you are right

Answer (score 0):

If order of the requests doesn't matter you could just remove the call from inside the if clause and remove the else.

```
closeAccount(): void {
    ... 

    if (comment) {
        this.apiService.addComment(id, comment).subscribe(); 
    } 

    this.apiService.closeAccount(id).subscribe(() => {
       // now do something
    });
}
```

If the order matters, you could setup the observable for the request based on the condition, and then call subscribe on the resulting one.

```
 closeAccount(): void {
    ...
    const request = comment 
      ?  this.apiService.addComment(id, comment).pipe(
           switchMap(_ => this.apiService.closeAccount(id))
         ) 
      : this.apiService.closeAccount(id);

    request.subscribe(() => {
       // now do something
    });
}
```

Cheers